# C++ cannot execute binary file

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, header-files

I just compiled my source using g++ with:

```
g++ -o exec Test.hpp
```

This is not generating an executable file and even if I make it executable using ***chmod*** I get this error.

```
bash: ./exec: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Here's my source:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {

  void main() {
    std::cout << "testing" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

I'm using Manjaro and it is not a virtual machine.
Any suggestion?

Comment: The question is _where_ did you compile it?

Comment: What's the contents of `Test.hpp`? It's pretty unusual to have a header file as the main program translation unit.

Comment: What does `file ./exec` show?

Comment: @Barmar ./exec: GCC precompiled header (version 014) for C++

Comment: It's just a class with the main function that prints "hello".. I just made this class to make a test because I'm working on a project but I cant generate an executable file for it

Comment: What you have is a precompiled header, not a program. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html You also can't have "a class with the main function". main needs to be a standalone function. Lots of things wrong here. I suggest making a cpp file with main, and including your header file there.

Comment: What is the extension of the `exec` file?  Try `ls -al exec*`.  Add answer to your post.

Comment: Remember C++ requires it's main method to live outside a class. And classes are optional here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC identifies the content/type of a file by extension, and ".hpp" is presumed to be a header file(1). Compiling a header file produces a pre-compiled-header file which is binary and non-executable.

The solution is to rename the file to ".cpp"(2) or adding "-x c++"

```
g++ -o exec Test.cpp
g++ -o exec -x c++ Test.cpp
```

(1) See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC5 "For any given input file, the file name suffix determines what kind of compilation is done:"

(2) Or any of .cc, .cp, .cxx, .cpp, .c++ or .C, See (1)